# Jupyter does not show symlink folder

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a folder that is a symbolic link to another folder on my hard drive. It is not shown in the folder list on Jupyter notebook.  How can I fix this?

(I'm running ubuntu 16.04).

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Somehow Jupyter Notbook does not want to follow symlinks, I managed to make it work by mounting a folder. Basically from a folder which is your home to notebook

```
mkdir mounted_folder
sudo mount --bind /absolute/path/to/some/folder mounted_folder
```

Just make sure that you first mount the folder and then launch the Notebook server. Otherwise it did not want to work for me.

Comment: You can also use `bindfs` (installed separately) that not required root.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ `bindfs -n /absolute/path/to/some/folder mounted_folder`

Comment: and did you need to include that in your fstab?

Comment: I used it in a bash script that starts Jupyter Notebook, but fstab could be another way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem trying to symlink a folder inside a Docker jupyter container (the volume was mounted but wasn't accessible to the jupyter account).

Normally a symlinked folder should be visible, unless the target folder lacks read permissions for the user trying to access.

An appropriate `chmod` command on the target folder fixed it for me and the folder appeared in the jupyter UI.